# Change bcrypt cost with Laravel Auth/Hash

Tags: authentication, hash, laravel-4, bcrypt

Is there any way to use Laravel's Auth and Hash, but change the bcrypt cost?

The default is defined here http://laravel.com/api/source-class-Illuminate.Hashing.BcryptHasher.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the `make` method.

You can pass an options array as the second parameter, where you can define the cost value.

`Hash::make('stringtobehashed', array('cost' => 20));`

Comment: Oh right I might have over-though this. `Auth` doesn't need to know the cost because it is saved with the hash and salt.

Answer (score 1):

I know this thread is very old, but just for quick reference,

If you're using Laravel 4.0 and up, change `cost` to `rounds`. You can look at the code [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/4.0/src/Illuminate/Hashing/BcryptHasher.php#L12).

EDIT:

Alternatively and as of Laravel 4.2, you can set the `rounds` once and for all, in some ServiceProvider's `boot` method (probably in the `AppServiceProvider`), using:
 `Hash::setRounds(12);`